# Is there a way to detect if the Facebook Javascript SDK loaded successfully?

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

I use Facebook as the membership system of my website. It uses the  code to generate a login control, allowing users to login via their facebook account. It's essentially one click if they're already a member, 2 if they're not (for granting permissions).

I got a problem though... feedback is suggesting the login button isn't always loading correctly. Instead of loading the facebook login control, it simply states (in text) "login via facebook" - which is what the login button would say if the control loaded successfully.

Testing shows that is what happens when the facebook javascript SDK fails to load completely (for whatever reason). I've seen instances where a # in the url prevents the SDK from loading.

To better support this issue, how would I go about detecting if the facebook javascript SDK loaded, and is ready? That way, if it fails, I can leave some sort of note for the user.

Here's how it's currently added to the page:

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
FB.init({
  appId: '***************',
  status: true,
  cookie: true,
  xfbml: true
});
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) {
  window.location.reload();
});

};
(function () {
  var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
  e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
  document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
} ());

</script>
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You should load the [Javascript Library Asynchronously](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) and put all your FB related functions inside the `window.fbAsyncInit` method:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>
```

> This code loads the SDK asynchronously so it does not block loading
>   other elements of your page. This is particularly important to ensure
>   fast page loads for users and SEO robots.
>
> The URLs in the above code are protocol relative. This lets the
>   browser to load the SDK over the same protocol (HTTP or HTTPS) as the
>   containing page, which will prevent "Insecure Content" warnings.
>
> The function assigned to `window.fbAsyncInit` is run as soon as the SDK
>   is loaded. Any code that you want to run after the SDK is loaded
>   should be placed within this function and after the call to `FB.init`.
>   For example, [this is where you would test the logged in status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9FfD.jpg) of the
>   user or [subscribe to any Facebook events](http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk) in which your application is
>   interested.

A quick example is the following:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  var isLoaded = false;
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });
    isLoaded = true;

    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  function checkIfLoaded() {
    if(isLoaded) console.log("LOADED!");
    else console.log("NOT YET!");

    return false;
  }

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="checkIfLoaded();">Check</a>
```

[image]
(*Just clicked the `check` link a couple of times*)

---

Please note that you can still construct the Login Link server-side and **WITHOUT** JavaScript. Example using the [PHP-SDK](http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk):

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
...
...
<a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">
    <img src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/zB6N8/hash/4li2k73z.gif">
</a>
```

Comment: @ifaour - thanks, excellent write up. Have you ever run into the issue before? It's strange, one page load the SDK loads fine. On another, it simply doesn't (hit refresh and it's working again...) It's rather hard to pin down why this is occurring.

Comment: @AwaisQarni: Thanks man. I would love to have a quick chat with you on GTalk if this is possible.

Comment: @Chad: Now that's the hard part when loading resources as it could be anything, Network or coding error or simply a Facebook bug just like the latest [bug](http://developers.facebook.com/live_status) (**SSL Warning on IE7 and IE8 when including all.js**).

Comment: @ifaour: Ya... I assumed it would be like finding a needle in a haystack. Have you personally experienced this issue?

Comment: @ifour. Bro at this time I am at office. Here I cannot do private chat. Well give me your id. I will add you and we can have chat at nite.(Nite means here we are having 2:00 PM. We can have chat after 8). Its an honour for me.

Comment: @Chad: Nope not really, at least no one complained till now! :P

Comment: This is not a good way to do it, use events instead:

`window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({appId: "#{KeyManager.facebook_app_id}", status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
  jQuery('#fb-root').trigger('facebook:init');
};`

Comment: might want to check FB is not null before using it to init(). Some businesses block facebook.

Answer (score 10):

Trigger an event when the SDK is loaded:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({appId: "#{KeyManager.facebook_app_id}", status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
  jQuery('#fb-root').trigger('facebook:init');
};
```

And listen for the event like this:

```
$("#fb-root").bind("facebook:init", function() {
  ..
});
```

Comment: I need to *wait until* the API is loaded, not just determine if it *is* loaded. For my purposes, this is much better than the accepted answer (listening for a custom event is better than setting a global and polling for it)

Answer (score 5):

If you are using jQuery (and you have loaded jQuery prior to the FB initialization) you can use a Deferred to run additional initialization.

```
<script>
    window.fbLoaded = $.Deferred();

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

        FB.init({
            appId      : '----------',
            xfbml      : true,
            status     : true,
            version    : 'v2.7'
        });

        window.fbLoaded.resolve();
    };


    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>
```

Then elsewhere (in a JS file) you can do this (in fact the key of this method is you can put this in as many places as you want and they will all get triggered):

```
 window.fbLoaded.done(function () { alert('FB initialized'); });
```

Note: If the initialization completes BEFORE you add the `done` event it will fire immediately (that is how Deferreds work). So you can put it wherever you want.

Be sure to test what you want the behavior to be if the API is never initializaed (just comment out the `(function(d,s,id)... part`

Answer (score 4):

Just look for FB object after loading FB JS SDK sync/async as given:

```
            if (typeof FB !== 'undefined') {
                alert("FB JS API is available now");
            } else {alert("do something...")}
```

That's a enough check to call any Facebook JS API related method safely.

Comment: I believe there is a race condition here if you are calling `FB.init(params)` from within your `fbAsyncInit` callback function. `FB` can be defined before `init` has been called. I would randomly get errors 1 in 10 times due to this.

Answer (score 4):

## Promise-based version, for modern browsers

```
// Load Facebook JS SDK
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.11';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

// Create a new promise, set to resolve using the global function `fbAsyncInit`,
// which the Facebook JS SDK will call once it's ready.
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  window.fbAsyncInit = resolve;
}).then(() => {
  // ... your code here ...
});
```

Answer (score 3):

What globals does this JS file introduce?

Let's say it creates a

```
var FaceBook = function() {//make friends! Or whatever...}
```

You can test for `if (FaceBook)` and go from there.

It seems likely that they give you some sort of load event for when their framework is booted up, so to speak.

Answer (score 3):

According to this page http://www.techsirius.com/2014/04/detect-social-SDK-didnt-load.html

```
$(window).load(function(){
   if(typeof window.FB == 'undefined'){
       alert('Facebook SDK is unable to load, display some alternative content for visitor');
   }
   else{
      alert('Facebook is working just fine');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Load the script dynamically (add a script tag from js) and check for error / success events.

Comment: This is not sufficient.  The Facebook JS SDK may load additional items after its base script has loaded.  Simply checking for success events on the base script may miss important elements required.

Answer (score 0):

```
var FB;
jQuery.fbInit = function(app_id) {
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : app_id, 
            status     : true, 
            channelUrl: '#', 
            cookie     : true, 
            xfbml      : true  
        });
        FB = FB;
        getLoginStatus();
    };
    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/it_IT/all.js";
        d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
    }(document));

    $('<div />').attr('id','fb-root').appendTo('body');
};

/**
 * https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/
 */
function getLoginStatus() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            $('#fb-root').trigger('facebook:init',[response]);
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            $('#fb-root').trigger('facebook:init',[response]);
        } else {
            $('#fb-root').trigger('facebook:init',[response]);
        }
    });
}
```

If you want check the status from another javascript (with the suggestion of @Leo Romanovsky )

```
 $("#fb-root").on("facebook:init", function(event, response) {
        if(response.status === 'connected') {
            alert("logged with FB")
        }else{
            alert("No Logged with FB")
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this from few days :

```
var isLoaded = false;

$(document).on('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {
    if ($('#fb-root').length && !isLoaded) {
        isLoaded = true;

        // ...
    }
});
```

What do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in other answers; with thanks to @ifaour & @Leo Romanovsky; the best way to detect if the SDK is loaded successully is to trigger an event when the fbAsyncInit is called.

If the event is captured then the SDK is loaded. The code below shows how this could be achieved:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Fire an event when the FB library asynchronously is loaded
    $("#fb-root").trigger("facebook:init");

    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }
  (document, "script", "facebook-jssdk"));
</script>

// Somewhere else in the code
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#fb-root").bind("facebook:init", function () {
        console.log("The event is fired FB SDK object is ready to be used.");
    });
});
```

In the event that the event is not fired you could add a timer to check if FB object is 'undefined' and show the appropriate message.

**Note 1:** Downside there could a slight delay till this event is fired.

**Note 2:** "feedback is suggesting the login button isn't always loading correctly". I know that FFv49 private browsing blocks the call to fb.