# Why am I getting this error for my Facebook Like button?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-fql

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: _onloadHook is not defined
```

Why? My code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //Initialize facebook
        FB.init({
            appId  : '12345',
            status : true, // check login status
            cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml  : true, // parse XFBML
            channelUrl : 'http://www.abc.com/channel.html', // channel.html file
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<fb:send href="http://abc.com/blah" font="lucida grande" ref="codes_popup"></fb:send>
<fb:send href="http://abc.com/blah" font="lucida grande" ref="codes_popup"></fb:send>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: When I have multiple  this will happen. When I only have one "send" button , the error is not there.

For every extra "Send" button, the error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the Facebook Platform; it has already been reported as [bug #20041](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=20041).

Answer (score 0):

Place the Facebook JS library and JS code scripts *under* the `fb-root` div:

```
<!DOCTYPE html  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//Initialize facebook
    FB.init({
        appId  : 'XXX',
        status : true, // check login status
        cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml  : true, // parse XFBML
        channelUrl : 'http://www.abc.com/channel.html', // channel.html file
    });
</script>
<fb:send href="http://abc.com/blah" font="lucida grande" ref="codes_popup"></fb:send>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I put it in document.ready for JQuery but it's still happening

Comment: @ifaour: I have it directly under the `fb-root` div and I"m getting the same error as the OP. It seemed to have just started today.

Answer (score 0):

I have been getting the exact same error today.

As ifaour mentions, the FB documentation says that you need to place the FB `<script>` tags under the `<div id="fb-root"></div>`.  However, in his example and in the FB documentation, they put the scripts directly under the `<div id="fb-root"></div>`.  I was doing that and still getting the error the OP mentions.  I was finally able to solve the problem by moving the FB `<script>` tags to the very bottom of the page, right before the closing `</body>` tag.  I believe what was happening is that some of my other scripts were interfering with the loading of the FB scripts.  Hope that helps.

Comment: It's either what you mentioned OR you need to use [Asynchronous loading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334977/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-the-facebook-javascript-sdk-loaded-successfully/5336483#5336483)

Answer (score 0):

You should call the facebook javascript using the upgraded async method. This will make sure that the whole DOM is loaded so that the fb:root is already on the page.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId  : 'YOUR APP ID',
      status : true, // check login status
      cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml  : true,  // parse XFBML
      channelUrl  : 'http://www.yourdomain.com/channel.html', // Custom Channel URL
      oauth : true //enables OAuth 2.0
    });
  };

  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```

Also critically important is to add support for OAuth 2.0 http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/525/

```
oauth : true
```

As of Oct 1 if you don't have that your apps will stop working properly.