# String.format not a function

Tags: javascript, html, jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins

I'm using HTML publisher in hope to have a html page with some javascript codes running on hudson. The HTML code is like this:

```
<html>
    <head>

            <!--Load the AJAX API-->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../stringformat.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">

            ......

            sql=String.format("/.csv? select from table where exchange=`ABC......")

            </script>
    </head>
```

However, after a successful build, my html page doesn't show what it suppose to, and as I check the error console, it says

```
Error: TypeError: String.format is not a function
```

I have put my stringformat.js into the top folder, as the HTML publisher doesn't seem to allow the file to contain anything other than HTML files.

Can anyone tell me why the String.format is not loaded properly? Thanks!

PS: stringformat.js is the file i got from

http://www.masterdata.se/r/string_format_for_javascript/

The code should be working properly as this piece of code works outside the hudson

Comment: Are you sure that `../stringformat.js` is loaded?

Comment: And what does stringformat.js do? If it doesn't add `format` to `String.prototype`, I wouldn't expect it to work.

Comment: @Explosion Pills: I'm not 100% sure, but the code worked outside the hudson

Comment: Try putting the content of `stringformat.js` inline in the html file

Comment: Can you check your web server log to see if `../stringformat.js` was requested and served? Also, this might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618464/how-to-wait-for-another-js-to-load-to-proceed-operation#

Answer (score -2):

try code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>String format javascript</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    String.format = function() {
    var s = arguments[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length - 1; i++) {
    var reg = new RegExp("\\{" + i + "\\}", "gm");
    s = s.replace(reg, arguments[i + 1]);
    }
    return s;
    }
var _myString = String.format("hi {0}, i'am {1}","everybody", "stackoverflower");
function show(){
alert(_myString);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" name="btnTest" id="btnTest" value="Test string format" onclick="show();" /> 
</body>
</html>
```