# How to load javascript step by step with QWebEngineView and qtwebchannel.js?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, pyqt5, qtwebengine

I'm setting up like a framework who use python in backend and html/css/js for frontend. My problem arrived during the loading of a QWebEngineView.

I search on the web how to establish a communication between python and javascript with QWebEngineView and I finally tried to use QtWebChannel.
So I setted up everything, and everything worked good with communication between python and javascript, but the next issue appeared:

- First: i can't load javascript files directly in html with tags `<script>`
- Second: javascript loaded randomly, i tried to load javascript from python with `my_view.page().runJavascript(my_js)` but it work one try on two. So sometimes jQuery load at the end, so an other part of the code doesn't work.

base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <p id="log"></p>
    <script src="qrc:///qtwebchannel/qwebchannel.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.onerror = function (error, url, line) {
            console.error("ERROR: " + error.toString());
            console.error("LINE: " + line.toString());
         };
        function load_app(){
            new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function (channel) {
                window.app = channel.objects.app;
                app.load_javascript(function(ret){
                    console.error("load javascript: " + ret)
                });
            });
         }
        load_app();
        console.error("app loaded")
    </script>
    {{ application_html_content | safe }}
</html>
```

Another part of HTML:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="row">
        {% for user_id, user in user_dict.items() %}
            <div id="{{ user_id }}" class="col s12 m6">
                <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
                    <div class="card-content white-text">
                        <span class="card-title">Visit Card</span>
                        <p>{{ user.name }}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-action">
                        <button id="btn_del_{{ user_id }}" class="btn blue waves-effect waves-light" onclick="delete_user({{ user_id }})">Delete</button>
                        <button class="btn blue waves-effect waves-light" onclick="detail_user({{ user_id }})">Detail</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block javascript %}
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
           app.request_result.connect(function (result) {
                if ("delete" in result) {
                    user_id = result.delete;
                    var element = document.getElementById(user_id);
                    element.parentNode.removeChild(element)
                }
            });
            console.error("ready");
        });

        function delete_user(user_id) {
            document.getElementById("btn_del_" + user_id).innerHTML = "Waiting ...";
            app.request('DemoHtml:Default:delete', user_id);
        }
        function detail_user(user_id) {
            app.path('detail_user', {"user_id": user_id});
        }
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

load_javascript function:

```
JQUERY = "vendor/Resources/js/jquery.js"
MATERIALIZE = "vendor/Resources/css/materialize/js/materialize.js"

@pyqtSlot(result=str)
def load_javascript(self):
    with open(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])), self.MATERIALIZE), "r") as m_stream:
        materialize_content = m_stream.read()
    with open(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])), self.JQUERY), "r") as j_stream:
        jquery_content = j_stream.read()
    self.template_view.view.page().runJavaScript(jquery_content)
    self.template_view.view.page().runJavaScript(materialize_content)
    return "ok"
```

As you can see, normally I must see in log error:

- First: "load javascript: ok"
- Second: "app loaded"

but one time one two, this is reverse like:

- js: app loaded
- js: ERROR: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
- js: LINE: 67
- js: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
- js: load javascript: ok

Any help for this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You might need to wait for the script been executed ? There is a [callback function](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#runJavaScript-2)

Comment: The [runJavaScript](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#runJavaScript) is asynchronous, so you must wait for the result before calling it again.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer so when my function `load_javascript()` is call, i can set a callback in `runJavascript()` to force the loading of the page waiting for the end ? @ekhumoro how can i wait for the result ? the `runJavaScript()` just load jQuery

Comment: @FlorianCouderc As explained in the linked docs, a calback passed to `runJavascript` will be invoked when it returns. So just chain the `runJavascript` calls together, rather than calling them one after the other. You could also create a wrapper function with a local event-loop that blocks until the callback is invoked. That would effectively make a synchronous version of `runJavascript`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem, thanks to @ekhumoro for trying to help me, i found an answer on this thread:

**How to wait for another JS to load to proceed operation ?**:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/8618519/8293533

So to make it work, i change my javascript to this:
I named this file `app.js`

```
function set_app() {
    try{
        new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function (channel) {
            window.app_channel = channel.objects.app;
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.error("setting_app error: " + e)
    }
}

set_app();

function request(route, args) {
    let interval = 10;
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        if (window["app_channel"]) {
            app_channel.request(route, args)
        } else {
            try {
                set_app();
            }
            catch(error) {
                console.error("app load error: " + error)
            }
            window.setTimeout(arguments.callee, interval);
        }
    }, interval)
}

function path(route, args) {
    let interval = 10;
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        if (window["app_channel"]) {
            app_channel.path(route, args)
        } else {
            try {
                set_app();
            }
            catch(error) {
                console.error("app load error: " + error)
            }
            window.setTimeout(arguments.callee, interval);
        }
    }, interval)
}

function request_result(callback) {
    let interval = 10;
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        if (window["app_channel"]) {
            app_channel.request_result.connect(callback)
        } else {
            try {
                set_app();
            }
            catch(error) {
                console.error("app load error: " + error)
            }
            window.setTimeout(arguments.callee, interval);
        }
    }, interval)
}
```

I erase my code `load_javascript` in python because i found the way to call js with `<script>` tags and `qrc:///` path.

Now my html head look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <p id="log"></p>
    <script src="qrc:///qwebchannel.js"></script>
    <script src="qrc:///app.js"></script>
    <script src="qrc:///jquery.js"></script>
    {{ application_html_content | safe }}
    <script src="qrc:///materialize.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

To use `qrc:///xxx.js` i used `QResource` and `.qrc`, `.rcc` files.
This is an example of my code for those who want:

```
class ApplicationContainer:

    SRC_QRC_PATH = "src/*Bundle/Resources/qrc/*.qrc"
    SRC_RCC_PATH = "src/*Bundle/Resources/qrc/*.rcc"
    VENDOR_QRC_PATH = "vendor/*Bundle/Resources/qrc/*.qrc"
    VENDOR_RCC_PATH = "vendor/*Bundle/Resources/qrc/*.rcc"

    def __init__(self):
        self.__pyqt_application = QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.__pyqt_resources = QResource()
        self.set_rcc_files()

    @property
    def application(self):
        return self.__pyqt_application

    @application.setter
    def application(self, new_app: QApplication):
        self.__pyqt_application = new_app

    def set_rcc_files(self):
        qrc_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])), self.SRC_QRC_PATH))
        qrc_files += glob.glob(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])), self.VENDOR_QRC_PATH))
        for qrc in qrc_files:
            subprocess.call(["rcc", "-binary", qrc, "-o", qrc[:-3] + "rcc"])

        rcc_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])), self.SRC_RCC_PATH))
        rcc_files += glob.glob(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])), self.VENDOR_RCC_PATH))

        for rcc in rcc_files:
            self.__pyqt_resources.registerResource(rcc)
```

As you can see i use `rcc`command, not `pyrcc5`

To finish, this is my `.qrc` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC>
<RCC version="1.0">
    <qresource>
        <file alias="jquery.js">../js/jquery.js</file>
        <file alias="app.js">../js/app.js</file>
        <file alias="qwebchannel.js">../js/qwebchannel.js</file>
        <file alias="materialize.js">../css/materialize/js/materialize.js</file>
        <file alias="materialize.css">../css/materialize/css/materialize.css</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

I know there can be a lot of improvment and optimisation in javascript code and python code. But it works like this !

Thank's and hope i help someone too.