# jQuery .click() doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to automatically click a button on a web page. I have the following code to do so:

```
let script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js";
script.type = "text/javascript";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

$("button.myButton").click();
```

When i run it, it doesn't click the button. Help.

Comment: You probably need to wait for the script to load.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to wait for another JS to load to proceed operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618464/how-to-wait-for-another-js-to-load-to-proceed-operation)

Comment: Do you see any errors in your console?

Comment: I bet the console is saying `$ is not defined`, which would mean jQuery isn't loaded yet. Why not use a regular `<script>` tag to load jQuery, instead of adding it programmatically?

Comment: @freedomn-m my bad - I had that issue previously but it seems to no longer be the case. I'll remove the comment to remove the misinformation.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The rest of the comment was useful...