# JQuery only excecutes after Alert in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, firefox

I'm trying to add a 'like' in my database with the 'changeRating()' method when a user clicks a local like button, a fb like button or a Twitter button.

But my 'likes' do not increase when a user clicks those buttons in Firefox, in Chrome everything works fine. In Firefox it only works when the **alert** in the beginning of the JQuery is activated?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        //alert('test'); (when this is activated it works)

        $(".fb-like").mouseup(function () {

            var vraagIdToUpdate = $(".vraagid").attr("value");

            if (vraagIdToUpdate != '') {
                changeRating(vraagIdToUpdate);
            }
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
        function (response) {
            var vraagIdToUpdate = $(".vraagid").attr("value");

            if (vraagIdToUpdate != '') {
                changeRating(vraagIdToUpdate);
            }
        });

       $(".twitter-share-button").mouseup(function () {
            var vraagIdToUpdate = $(".vraagid").attr("value");

            if (vraagIdToUpdate != '') {
                changeRating(vraagIdToUpdate);
            }
        });

        twttr.events.bind('click', function () {
            var vraagIdToUpdate = $(".vraagid").attr("value");

            if (vraagIdToUpdate != '') {
                changeRating(vraagIdToUpdate);
            }
        });

        $("#stemknop").click(function () {
            //voeg event handler toe aan de click-functie op de link (die als className twitter-share-button heeft meegekregen)
            var vraagIdToUpdate = $(".vraagid").attr("value");
            //alert('gelukt');
            $(this).css({ 'opacity': '0.4' });

            if (vraagIdToUpdate != '') {
                changeRating(vraagIdToUpdate);
            }
        });

        function changeRating(vraagId) {
            //Maak een JSON object aan met dezelfde property-name als ons Model classe
            var shareModel = { vraagID: vraagId };

            $.post("/api/ShareAPI/ChangeNumberOfShares", shareModel).success(function (result) { $('.aantalStemmen').text(result.newAantalShares) });
        }
    });
```

I know that there is posibly something that loads too fast or isn't there when a bit of code needs that specific thing... The alert() causes my code to 'wait' and so it does work. But I can't seem to find what bit of code causes this problem.

Edit: my firefox console states the following:

> ReferenceError: FB is not defined Vraag:143 ReferenceError: FB is not
>   defined Vraag:247 Gebruik van getUserData() of setUserData() wordt
>   niet meer ondersteund. Gebruik in plaats daarvan WeakMap of
>   element.dataset. requestNotifier.js:64 "Invalid App Id: Must be a
>   number or numeric string representing the application id." sdk.js:53
>   "The "fb-root" div has not been created, auto-creating" sdk.js:53 "No
>   callback passed to the ApiClient" sdk.js:53 Error: Container is not
>   defined format+nl,default+nl,ui+nl,corechart+nl.I.js:130 Gebruik van
>   getUserData() of setUserData() wordt niet meer ondersteund. Gebruik in
>   plaats daarvan WeakMap of element.dataset. requestNotifier.js:64
>   Gebruik van getPreventDefault() wordt niet meer ondersteund. Gebruik
>   in plaats daarvan defaultPrevented. jquery-1.8.2.js:3260 Error:
>   Container is not defined

Comment: may be FB.Event. or twttr.events.

Comment: I guess the code is asynchronous and takes some time to load, when you have the alert it gives the browser an extra second to download/execute in the background

Comment: Yes I'm inclined to agree with @crisbeto.  Make sure you are loading the FB JS before the javascript you are calling in your code above.

Comment: How should I force this code to load before that code?

Comment: Try looking around the facbook API, most likely they have a callback when everything has been loaded

Comment: I think the callback method will be the solution but I don't really know how to implement it

Answer (score 0):

change your post request to ajax and make the request synchronous :
For eg :

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: "/api/ShareAPI/ChangeNumberOfShares",
   data: shareModel,
   success: function(result) {
                  $('.aantalStemmen').text(result.newAantalShares);
              },
   async:false
});
```

Comment: The same error's as in my post, FB is undefined etc

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Try looking at the answers here too [Is there a way to detect if the Facebook Javascript SDK loaded successfully?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334977/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-the-facebook-javascript-sdk-loaded-successfully)

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        //alert('test'); (when this is activated it works)

        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function (response) {
            var vraagIdToUpdate = $(".vraagid").attr("value");

            if (vraagIdToUpdate != '') {
                changeRating(vraagIdToUpdate);
            }

            $(".fb-like").mouseup(function () {

                var vraagIdToUpdate = $(".vraagid").attr("value");

                if (vraagIdToUpdate != '') {
                    changeRating(vraagIdToUpdate);
                }
            });

            $(".twitter-share-button").mouseup(function () {
                var vraagIdToUpdate = $(".vraagid").attr("value");

                if (vraagIdToUpdate != '') {
                    changeRating(vraagIdToUpdate);
                }
            });

            twttr.events.bind('click', function () {
                var vraagIdToUpdate = $(".vraagid").attr("value");

                if (vraagIdToUpdate != '') {
                    changeRating(vraagIdToUpdate);
                }
            });

            $("#stemknop").click(function () {
                //voeg event handler toe aan de click-functie op de link (die als className twitter-share-button heeft meegekregen)
                var vraagIdToUpdate = $(".vraagid").attr("value");
                //alert('gelukt');
                $(this).css({ 'opacity': '0.4' });

                if (vraagIdToUpdate != '') {
                    changeRating(vraagIdToUpdate);
                }
            });

            function changeRating(vraagId) {
                //Maak een JSON object aan met dezelfde property-name als ons Model classe
                var shareModel = { vraagID: vraagId };

                $.post("/api/ShareAPI/ChangeNumberOfShares", shareModel).success(function (result) { $('.aantalStemmen').text(result.newAantalShares) });
            }
        });
    });
```